# T invariance in flavored meson system

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, cp-violation, mesons

Consider Kaon CP conjugate states $\left|K^{0}\right>$ and $\left|\bar{K^{0}}\right>$. The physical states i.e, eigenstates of effective hamitonian can be written as 
\begin{equation}
\left|M_{a}\right> =p_{a}  \left|M^{0}\right> +q_{a} \left|\bar{M^{0}}\right> 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left|M_{b}\right> =p_{b}  \left|M^{0}\right> -q_{b} \left|\bar{M^{0}}\right>
\end{equation}

Now, T invariance requires that $\dfrac{p_{a}}{q_{a}}= \dfrac{q_{b}}{p_{b}} $. Can anybody explain this condition using more logic than mathematics?